# How to zip files with japanese names in csharp?

Tags: sharpziplib

I am using "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip" namespace to zip the files. I want to zip some files with japanese names. When i zip using ZipOutputStream i am getting junk filenames. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You could try http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ as a reeplacement, not sure if it handles it better.